# Delete a row from gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to delete a row from gridview on rowdataBound() event but get Procedure or function delete_row has too many arguments specified.
Below is the code

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Row != null) && (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++ )
        {
            GridView1.Rows[i].Attributes["style"] += "cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;";
            if (GridView1.DataKeys[i].Values[1].ToString() != "broken")
                GridView1.Rows[i].Attributes["onclick"] =
                    "window.open('" + GridView1.DataKeys[i].Values[0].ToString() + "','open_window', 'menubar, toolbar, location, directories, status, scrollbars, resizable, dependent, width=640, height=480, left=0, top=0')";
            else
            {
                GridView1.DeleteRow(i);
            }

        }

    }
```

HTML mark up is below, I have 3 DataKeyNames declared is that the problem

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenField1" runat="server" Value="" />

        <br />

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:User42ConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="lsp_show_by_letter" onselecting="SqlDataSource1_Selecting" 
            SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" DeleteCommand="delete_row" 
            DeleteCommandType="StoredProcedure">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="hiddenField1" DefaultValue=" " 
                    Name="letter" PropertyName="Value" Type="String" />
            </SelectParameters>
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter Name="link_Id" ControlID="hiddenField1" PropertyName="Value" Type="Int32" />
            </DeleteParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

    </div>

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
        AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" 
        DataKeyNames="link_url,link_description,link_id">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="link_display_string" 
                HeaderText="link_display_string" SortExpression="link_display_string" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="link_url"Visible="False" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="link_description" Visible="False" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="link_id" ReadOnly="true" Visible="False" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Delete row stored procedure is

```
  `ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.delete_row @link_Id int AS BEGIN DELETE FROM [links] WHERE ([link_id] = @link_Id) END`
```

Comment: Procedure or function delete_row has too many arguments specified.

Comment: What does deleterow function look like ?

Comment: @nikhil: it's not necessary to place "asp.NET C#" in the title, since you have that in the tags.

Comment: Is it me or does deleting from the database on a databound event seem like a bad idea?

Answer (score 2):

It's because your hiddenfiled is not bound to SqlDataSource and so it passes empty or null value to delete_row procedure. Since you are bounding your SQLDataSource directly to datagridview, you need to bound hideenfiled with selected row value of datagridview. This should help you trying few options but this is your base problem.